# sorting list with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I am having trouble with sorting a list with a particular order. I created 3 tuples and converted them into a list. I want the color of the car in all 3 tuples to be in the [1] index instead of the last one. I thought this would work but it just prints the list in the same order.

Comment: When do you expect `len(i) == 5` to ever be true?

Comment: i saw it on another post and I thought it would work. I just started learning python a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: Well, in your question, you said *"I thought this would work"*, so I suggest editing the question to include an explanation of *why* you thought it would work - otherwise it is hard to know what level to aim an answer at. Depending on your level of understanding, explaining what your problem is and how to solve it might take one sentence or rather significantly longer. So you need to be more specific in order to get an answer that will be useful to you.

Comment: `for i in allMyCars[:]:` Each time through the loop, `i` will be *one of the actual car tuples*, and **not** an integer.

Comment: Also, `allMyCars.insert(1, i)` attempts to modify the overall list of cars, not any of the individual car tuples - which you can *not* re-order in this way; that's not part of what tuples can do. (Aside from which, inserting something into a list that's already there will *not* remove the existing value.) You need to make *new* tuples in the appropriate order.

Comment: that explains so much. Thank you @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1):

Since `tuple` is immutable in python, you should create new tuples.

```
allMyCars = [(car[0], car[3], car[1], car[2]) for car in allMyCars]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I guess:

```
myCar = (2004, 'Ford', 'Mustang', 'green')    
myCar2 = (2014, 'Ford', 'Fusion', 'white')    
myCar3 = (1998, 'Chevrolet', 'S10', 'brown')

allMyCars = list((myCar, myCar2, myCar3))
for car in allMyCars:
    *rest, color = car
    newCar = (color, *rest)
    print(newCar)

# Output:
('green', 2004, 'Ford', 'Mustang')
('white', 2014, 'Ford', 'Fusion')
('brown', 1998, 'Chevrolet', 'S10')
```

Or,

```
allMyCars = [(color, *rest) for *rest, color in allMyCars]
```

EDIT based on comments:

```
allMyCars = [(year, color, *rest) for year, *rest, color in allMyCars]

#or

for car in allMyCars:
    year, *rest, color = car
    newCar = (year, color, *rest)
    print(newCar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuple in Python is immutable. Insertion is not allowed here. You need to make a list to do so. Or, you should make `myCar` variables as list.

```
myCar = [2004, 'Ford', 'Mustang', 'green']  
myCar2 = [2014, 'Ford', 'Fusion', 'white']    
myCar3 = [1998, 'Chevrolet', 'S10', 'brown']
allMyCars = [myCar, myCar2, myCar3]
for i in allMyCars:
    i.insert(1, i[-1])
    i.pop()
```

The last `i.pop()` was necessary because insertion is done, but the list still contains the color at the end (repetition of color element). So, it had to be popped out. After the above snippet runs, the output is

```
[[2004, 'green', 'Ford', 'Mustang'],
 [2014, 'white', 'Ford', 'Fusion'],
 [1998, 'brown', 'Chevrolet', 'S10']]
```